# Fast Fourier Transform in computer vision

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network, computer-vision, mathematics, fourier

Can someone explain me how does FFT works in computer vision, please. I know something about FFT as an algorithm of competitive programming but I can't understand how it perform an image in computer vision. For example, I had read this article https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2020/file/2fd5d41ec6cfab47e32164d5624269b1-Paper.pdf
but I didn't understand about FFT. For example, in the pseudocode on the 4th page they say that after FFT out image width will be halfed. But why? How does it works? Thank you in advance!